# Spyder Crashes During launch

Tags: python-3.x

## Here it says

Spyder crashed during last session.

If Spyder does not start at all and before submitting a bug report, please try to reset settings to defaults by running Spyder with the command line option '--reset':
spyder --reset

Warning: this command will remove all your Spyder configuration files located in '/Users/repair/.spyder-py3').

If restoring the default settings does not help, please take the time to search for known bugs or discussions matching your situation before eventually creating a new issue here. Your feedback will always be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cant open Spyder. I have a midterm soon and I cant practice programming because of this. Pls help.

Comment: You probably should use [Super User](https://superuser.com/about) for getting help.

Answer (score 0):

you shall run

```
pip install --upgrade spyder
```